# basic ruby testing question

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing

I've found myself doing this a lot lately... how can I improve the declaration of the paperclip fixture? (sorry, noob question I know)

```
class ProjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def xxx
    project = Project.new({
      :name => 'xxx', 
      :attachment => File.new(Rails.root + 'test/fixtures/files/attachments/xxx.psd')
    })
    project.save
    project
  end





  test "should not save project without name" do
    assert xxx, "Saved project without a name"
  end

  test "should save a project with an attachment and have a valid directory" do
    assert File.directory?(xxx.directory), "Saved project without establishing a valid directory"
  end

  test "should save a project with an attachment and have a URL" do
    assert !xxx.filename.nil?, "Saved project without establishing a valid URL"
  end

  test "should save a project with an attachment and have a valid absolute file path" do
    assert File.exists?(xxx.absolute_filename), "Saved project without establishing a valid absolute filename"
  end

  test "should save a project with an attachment and have a valid base filename" do
    assert !xxx.base_filename.nil?, "Saved project without establishing a valid base filename"
  end
end
```

Comment: paperclip "fixture" is def xxx, sorry for no syntax highlighting, first time on this site

Answer (score 2):

Recognizing that answers to this are subjective and heavily dependent on what the rest of your system looks like, here are some thoughts I hope will be of value:

1 - If your fixtures use the filesystem much, take a look at the FakeFS gem: https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs

2 - Though for some cases, having fixture creation in the same file as the tests themselves is perfectly reasonable, I find the case of wanting them separate more common. This enables reuse - both for other tests and for building relationships to other data as the system evolves. Obviously up to you, just something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

the classic way of using fixtures in rails is to create a yaml fixture file, something like this:

```
record1:
  name: xxxx
  attachment: test/fixtures/files/attachements/xxx.psd

record2:
  .... etc.
```

store this in test/fixtures/projects.yml

then at the top of your test, write:

fixtures :projects

and this will load the fixtures in your fixtures file into the database, at which time you can carry out whichever tests you want.

Answer (score 0):

Also  have a look at solutions like [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or [Machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist) - fixture replacements which let you define factories for test entities using a Ruby DSL.